# Ubuntu Server VMware www folder not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, lamp

I have an Ubuntu server setup in VMware workstation and if you load the IP from ifconfig you get "Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page" with the messsage "It works!"

However when I put a file into /var/www like info.php and then attempt to load that page using serverip/info.php i get 404 not found.

I have checked the directory and tried many files in the www folder but nothing seems to work :(

Comment: If nothing works, you're probably putting these files in the wrong directory. Check your Apache configuration

Comment: have you tried to put just a text file in there to see if it works.  Also be sure to (as @Volk noted), check your config - httpd.conf

Comment: Yeah I checked the apache2.conf file and /var/www is enabled

Comment: If I dir /var/www/ I get a list of all the files, info.php tried a txt.txt and test.html I'm really a big noobie at linux terminal but I don't see what could be wrong except maybe my IP in browser or something like that but Apache page is coming up

Comment: You need to check httpd.conf (or apache2.conf) file, see if /var/www/ is really your DocumentRoot. You can find it in /etc/apache2/

Comment: My exact apach2.conf 
<directory /var/www>
Allowoveride none
Require all granted
</directory>

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the files needed to be put in /var/www/html folder 
I don't know why even though apache2.conf states /www/ folder as be accessible by web 
this is the folder where the actually files need to be :o